# what ruby client is the most stable for rabbitmq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabbitmq

What ruby client should I use for rabbitmq?

Would I just connect to the rabbitmq server once during the web application startup i.e. in a initializer or would this be done on a per request basis?

Does doing it once during startup have any concurrency issues?

Answer (score 1):

I have had good success in production with the Carrot gem. https://github.com/famoseagle/carrot Our code connects once per request.

There are a lot of issues that arise when you maintain a connection globally for the application. If you can avoid it, I would recommend against.

Comment: We use a mix of Scala and .NET based clients for backend work